# Simple Delphi TTimer Program

Tags: delphi, timer, countdown

can anyone help me how to display a simple timer using TTimer component in Delphi? I have a  label where will the countdown from 5-0 will be displayed. Please help. Just a simple one. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't say what the time interval between 5 and 0 is, but I'll assume that it's seconds. You need to define a global variable of type integer with an initial value of 5 (I'll call it 'countdown'), and a timer with an interval of 1000. Its OnTimer method will be as follows:

```
Procedure Timer1Timer (sender: TObject);
begin
 if countdown > 0 then
  begin
   dec (countdown);
   label1.caption:= inttostr (countdown)
  end
 else timer1.enabled:= false
end;
```

When you want the countdown to commence, enable the timer and set the label's caption to be '5'.